# How can i get a time data for video stream?

Tags: android, video-streaming, buffering

I study android.

How can i calculate and predict a time that is video buffering when use video streaming.

It will calculate time when showing video streaming.(ex youtube)

1. How catch a point of start and end streaming.
2. How catch a point of start and end buffering.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onBufferingUpdate to catch buffer percantage

```
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Timer` object?  [Android Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and make it increment an object every 1000 ms.